# Trim function to concatenate results from conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am attempting to build a simple workflow notification-type system. The condition needs to check two things:

1. The date is less than 5 days from today (between 0 and 5)
2. The answer is not "Yes"

Then with that, the result shows up with the applicable row in column A.

I am trying to use the TRIM function so that I can concatenate potentially multiple different workflow task messages. As shown in A13 below.

However, the formula is not factoring in the date part of the formula. That or I have it written wrong and cannot figure it out.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? In the example shown below. Neither of the messages, "Invite 1" or "Invite 2" should be showing. The reason being is they are not 5 days or less out from today.

```
=TRIM(
  IF(AND($AA13-TODAY()>=-5,$AC13<>"Yes"),"Invite 1","")
  & " "
  & IF(AND($AD13-TODAY()>=-5,$AF13<>"Yes"),"Invite 2","")
)
```

[image]

Comment: If the content of `$AA13` needs to be less than five days in the future, then you need to use `$AA13-TODAY()<=5`

Comment: also check whether you want greater than or less than, I think you also need an additional condition to check the lower range of -0-

Comment: @gns100 What do you mean? Could you provide more context?

Comment: @user1530279, it wasn't clear when you want to have the result be `Invite 1` vs blank. If you want it to say invite 1 when the date is between 0 and 5 days from today and NOT yes, then the AND section should be something like: `AND($AA13-TODAY()>=0,$AA13-TODAY()<=5,$AC13<>"Yes")`

Comment: inviting someone where the answer is negative wouldn't make sense that's why you have the lower limit of -0- or possibly 1...